# Connecting to remote Cassandra server shows NoHostAvailableException

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

There are many questions regarding Cassandra `NoHostAvailableException`. Even after following many of them yet I am unable to fix this issue.

From my local machine I can not access cassandra DB using java.

**java code is:** (*In remote server*)

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

public class Read_Data {

    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{

        //queries
        String query = "select title,hotel_id,comment from agoda_kuchikomi limit 1";

        //Creating Cluster object
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("172.15.81.249").build();

        //Creating Session object
        Session session = cluster.connect("kuchikomi");

        //Getting the ResultSet
        ResultSet result = session.execute(query);

        System.out.println(result.all());
    }
}
```

**Error is**

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /172.15.81.249:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/172.15.81.249:9042] Cannot connect))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:232)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:79)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.negotiateProtocolVersionAndConnect(Cluster.java:1600)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1518)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:159)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:330)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:280)
    at Read_Data.main(Read_Data.java:17)
```

Cassandra hosted in AWS ec2 instance.

my `cassandra.yaml` file has

`rpc_address: 0.0.0.0`  # I have changed it from 172.15.81.249 to 0.0.0.0

`broadcast_rpc_address: 172.15.81.249`

`native_transport_port: 9042`

`rpc_port: 9160`

Comment: can you access Cassandra by using `cqlsh`?

Comment: @Ev3rlasting in cassandra ec2 instance I can access DB using cqlsh. But my code is running in remote server.

Comment: you can also try to `cqlsh [remote ip] [remote port]` to see if it can access a remote cassandra server

Comment: I do not have cqlsh on remote server. So I am trying to access cassandra through Java code. After installing datastax driver.

Comment: Is it in a VPC? Did you open the port in AWS console?

Comment: Also, you're connecting to a private network address, not a public EC2 IP

Comment: @cricket_007 I have tried with public IP as well but the error is persistent.

Comment: Because you need to open the port to the public, or your IP... It's not an issue with the driver. You can use telnet, for example, to check open ports

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried `netstat -nltu `
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9042                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:36279               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 172.15.81.249:7000          0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN

`Similar to this many ports are open`

Comment: Sure, that's on Cassandra itself. I meant from the remote client. You use other methods to check an open port

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry to say but I did not understand what ports I need to check on the remote server. Can you please explain.

Comment: Assume your Java app runs on the same server as Cassandra. You connect to `127.0.0.1`. There's no firewall. You move your code anywhere else, you are subject to a firewall, despite a port listening. AWS VPC does not have a default open network between servers. And `telnet`, or similar tool, should probably be used to do port checking instead of starting a Java app and guessing at network addresses

Answer (score 0):

My AWS instance was not allowing my IP so I added some inbound rules on Cassandra AWS instance to allow ip where source code is present. And that's it.